# Game theory extensive form games

Tags: game-theory

I would like to have some help with this exercise, I can't seem to manage to understand how I could transform the problem into an extensive form game, or I don't need that to answer ?

[image]

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to first deduce the inherent logics, f.i. May 19 disqualifies (see Statement 1 by Albert). You'll find help online with this kind of deduction problem.

Then establish a game tree with Alberts options in layer 1, Bernards in layer 2 and Alberts conclusions in layer 3 if there is one.
E.g. May 19 would lead to Albert being able to pinpoint the date immediately; as this hurts the given conditions, it ends there.

I'd say what matters in general is you being able to somehow draw the deductive steps needed to answer the problem; however, if your exercise is explicitely in ext form game, I'd choose to visualize the solutions path in a game tree.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried to make a tree out of the deductions but I didn't succeed. From a logical point of a view the outcome makes sense to me, but depicting it into a tree is something else. But I need it to be able to know each information partition after each round..